# Imprimindo linhas específicas de um arquivo texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Imaginem que tenho um arquivo texto chamado teste.txt com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
4 Março 2017- Sábado

    meu aniversario

    -prova de calculo



    6 Março 2017- Segunda

    aniversario do Salomao

    - fazer compras




    8 Março 2017- Quarta

    feriado

    -acordar tarde
```

O objetivo é verificar se uma string específica, como por exemplo, "6 Março 2017" está no arquivo (sua primeira ocorrência, se houver mais de uma) e depois imprimir "tudo" até antes da próxima data.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser verificar se "6 Março 2017" está no arquivo, eu deveria imprimir:

```
 6 Março 2017- Segunda

    aniversario do Salomao

    - fazer compras
```

Fiz o seguinte:

```
f = open("teste.txt",'r')
search = "6 Março 2017"
for  line in f:
    if search in line:

        print(line)
        break
```

Mas só imprimo:

```
6 Março 2017- Segunda
```

Como posso fazer o programa imprimir também as outras linhas que me interessam?

Eu tentei implementar uma logica mais simples e não deu certo:

após achar a data, com um simples :

if "6 Março 2017" in f.readlines():

Depois gostaria de fazer um **while** que percorresse as outras linhas, afinal já cheguei na primeira linha que desejo, que é a que contem " 6 Março 2017- Segunda" e imprimisse tudo até ANTES de encontrar outra data:

6 Março 2017- Segunda

```
aniversario do Salomao

- fazer compras
```

#### Ele para de imprimir, pois a próxima linha depois dos espaços em brancos começa com 8.

Alguém conseguiria mostrar este código?

Comment: Não entendi a edição ou o comentário na minha resposta. O código das DUAS respostas que vc tem fazem exatamente isso. Essa lógica "mais simples" está errada.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira: Desculpe, eu queria entender o erro no que eu pensei em fazer! As respotas são perfeitas

Comment: Bom, há vários erros. O principal é que `"6 Março 2017" in f.readlines()` apenas retorna verdadeiro se o texto *existe* na lista de linhas. Ele não indica qual é a linha onde o texto se encontra, e por isso não dá pra vc fazer qualquer outra coisa além de saber se existe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não sei do que se trata o seu problema (seria um exercício de faculdade?), mas se você está tentando construir uma agenda ou algo do tipo, eu sugeriria utilizar um formato de armazenamento mais apropriado e fácil de manipular.

> Se for algo mais amador, usando armazenamento em arquivo texto mesmo,
>   eu sugeriria usar um [JSON](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), um [XML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) ou um [YAML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Todos têm
>   pacotes prontos no Python. Se for algo mais profissional, talvez seja
>   melhor usar um banco de dados ([MySQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), por exemplo, que também tem
>   pacotes prontos no Python).

De todas as formas, há várias opções de fazer o que você deseja. Pra facilitar, eu sugiro utilizar o pacote `datetime` para identificar as datas. Mas para isso você precisa definir a localização em Português antes e, muito importante, *usar o nome do dia da semana de forma correta* ("Segunda-feira", ao invés de "Segunda").

O seguinte código faz a leitura linha a linha, testando cada linha para ver se encontra uma data (usa a função `datetime.strptime`, que lança uma exceção se não for uma data válida - quando eu considero como conteúdo da data anteriormente reconhecida, armazenada na variável `date`). Se for uma data, ele abre uma nova "chave" no dicionário `info` com base nessa data. Se não for, ele considera como um conteúdo daquela entrada da sua agenda, e simplesmente acumula ele na chave atual (ao fazer `info[date] += line + '\n'`).

Note que a "lógica" essencialmente é:

1. Lê uma linha, se ainda não chegou no final do arquivo.
2. Verifica se é uma data.
3. Se for uma data, abre um novo "registro" para ela, e volta ao passo 1.
4. Se não for uma data, adiciona a linha como conteúdo no registro atual. Volta ao passo 1.

Vc pode implementar essa lógica de qualquer forma, e o pulo do gato tá justamente no passo 2 (verificar se é uma data). Esse código apenas tenta facilitar essa identificação usando os pacotes `locale` e `datetime`. Mas nada te impede de usar [expressões regulares](http://turing.com.br/material/regex/python_re.html) ou mesmo comparação manual.

Eis o código:

```
import sys
import locale
from datetime import datetime

# Define a localização para Português do Brasil
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ptg_bra') # No Windows!
# Em outro OS provavelmente será:
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')

date = ''
info = {}
with open('teste.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():

        line = line.strip('\n ') # Remove quebras de linhas e espaços

        # Tenta converter a linha atual para uma data (no formato esperado!)
        # Se sucesso, abre uma nova "chave" de conteúdo
        try:
            key = datetime.strptime(line, '%d %B %Y- %A')
            date = key
            info[date] = ''

        # Se falhou, o conteúdo pertence à chave atual (se há uma)
        except ValueError:
            if date != '':
                info[date] += line + '\n'


date = input('Digite a data para consulta:')
try:
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %B %Y- %A')
except ValueError:
    print('O valor [{}] não é uma data válida.'.format(date))
    sys.exit(-1)

print(info[date])
```

Lembrando que a entrada tem que ser (com "segunda**-feira**" ao invés de só "segunda"):

```
4 Março 2017- Sábado

    meu aniversario

    -prova de calculo



    6 Março 2017- Segunda-feira

    aniversario do Salomao

    - fazer compras

[. . .]
```

A saída do código é essa:

```
>teste
Digite a data para consulta:6 Março 2017- Segunda-feira

aniversario do Salomao

- fazer compras
```

> P.S.: Observe que o formato da data está fixado como `dia Mês ano-
>   Dia_da_semana` com base no formato `%d %B %Y- %A`. Se você precisar
>   mudar o formato (nem que seja adicionando ou removendo um espaço!),
>   você precisa mudar o formato! A lista de formatos pode ser consultada
>   na documentação ou [neste guia rápido](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: NA verdade, é um exercicio hipotético para aprender os conceitos de manipulação de arquivos!

Comment: :Eu tentei implementar uma logica mais simples e não deu certo:


após achar a data, com um simples :

if "6 Março 2017" in f.readlines():


Depois gostaria de fazer um while que percorresse as outras linhas, afinal já cheguei na primeira linha que desejo, que é a que contem " 6 Março 2017- Segunda" e imprimisse tudo até ANTES de encontrar outra data:


 6 Março 2017- Segunda

    aniversario do Salomao

    - fazer compras

### Ele para de imprimir, pois a próxima linha depois dos espaços em brancos começa com 8.

Answer (score 6):

### Lógica

A lógica implementada é simples:

1. O conteúdo do arquivo é lido e armazenado em `content`
2. Armazena-se em `date` a data desejada
3. Com expressões regulares, busca-se no arquivo todas as datas no formato, armazenando em `dates`:

   - A data deve iniciar com um ou dois dígitos
   - Seguido de um espaço em branco
   - Seguido de qualquer caractere (para coincidir com caracteres *non-ASCII*) inúmeras vezes
   - Seguido de um espaço em branco
   - Sequido de quatro dígitos
4. Verifica-se se a data desejada existe no arquivo

   - Se não, dispare uma exceção com uma mensagem de erro
5. Localiza no arquivo a data desejada e armazena a posição em `start`
6. Verifica o índice da data desejada na lista de datas `dates`
7. Verifica se a data desejada não é a última presente no arquivo

   - Se for, define `end` como sendo a posição do último caractere do conteúdo do arquivo
8. Busca a próxima data no arquivo acessando o índice `index+1` de `dates`, armazenando em `next_date`
9. Localiza no arquivo a próxima data e armazena a posição em `end`
10. Exibe o conteúdo do arquivo entre as posições `start` e `end`

### Código

> Foi removido espaços em branco do conteúdo dado na pergunta para melhorar a apresentação da resposta, mas não é necessário para que o código funcione.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

content = """4 Março 2017- Sábado
meu aniversario
-prova de calculo

6 Março 2017- Segunda
aniversario do Salomao
- fazer compras

8 Março 2017- Quarta
feriado
-acordar tarde"""

# Data desejada:
date = "8 Março 2017"

# Localizando todas as datas no arquivo:
dates = re.findall(r"[0-9]{1,2}\s.+\s[0-9]{4}", content)

# Verifica se a data existe no arquivo:
if date not in dates:
    raise Exception("Data não definida")

# Localiza a data desejada no arquivo:
start = content.find(date)

# Verifica o índice da data na lista de datas:
index = dates.index(date)

# Verifica se não é a última data da lista:
if index < len(dates) - 1:

    # Verifica qual é a data posterior à desejada:
    next_date = dates[index + 1]

    # Localiza a próxima data no arquivo:
    end = content.find(next_date)

else:

    # É a última data da lista, então exibe até o final do arquivo:
    end = len(content)

# Exibe o conteúdo:
print(content[start:end])
```

### Saídas

Para `date = "4 Março 2017"`, gera-se a saída:

```
4 Março 2017- Sábado
meu aniversario
-prova de calculo
```

Para `date = "6 Março 2017"`, gera-se a saída:

```
6 Março 2017- Segunda
aniversario do Salomao
- fazer compras
```

Para `date = "8 Março 2017"`, gera-se a saída:

```
8 Março 2017- Quarta
feriado
-acordar tarde
```

Para `date = "10 Março 2017"`, gera-se a saída:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 25, in <module>
Exception: Data não definida
```

> Veja o código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GR2b/2) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/D3mJJz).